# content scrolling on canvas via mousemovement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to implement an infinite background scene scroll that is controlled by the ***mousemove*** on a canvas

I have the following in a ***requestAnimationFrame*** working almost right

```
 y1 = y1 >= h? y1 - h : y1; // y1 is the current mouse position on('drag') less the offset  if the position is greater than height of canvas reset with offset
 c.font="20px Georgia";
 c.clearRect(0,0, w, h); // w, h is the width and height of canvas
 c.save();
 //c.translate(0, y1);
 for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) { // number of images to be drawn to fill area
    var y = y1 + (i * im.height); // reposition the images relative to mouse position
    y = y >= h? - im.height + y1 : y; // if the image position is off screen then re position to top relative to mouse
    c.drawImage(im, 0, y, im.width, im.height);
 }
 c.fillText("y: " + y,10,190);
 c.restore();
```

However the problem comes in when I have reached the end of the canvas edges and need to "loop" the image... can't figure out how to reposition the images after going out of view in relation to the mouse position

Any insight on this?

**Update:**

I'm able to get a continuous scroll but I believe its being messed up by an ***e.preventDefault*** on the *document element* while i'm running the ***'touchmove'*** on the *canvas element* itself...

Is it safer to run the code on the **canvas or the document**?

Comment: Do you have problems because you don't have MouseEvents on the canvas anymore, or do you need a Method, to seemless attach the the start of your Image to the end?

Comment: Well I'm still trying to determine if the the former but I think its the latter.

Comment: Mmmh in that case I could only give you the hint that, what you want to build is called a parallax scroller, so maybe you can find more informations with that term

Answer (score 1):

**Here's one way of creating an infinite panorama:**

- Create a horizontally mirrored image from your source image.
- Create an animation loop that draws first the original & then the mirror image to the right of the original image..
- **Panning Visually Rightward**: With each loop, offset the images by 1 pixel leftward (offset--).  When the offset is the size of original+mirror width, then reset the offset to zero.
- **Panning Visually Leftward**: Start with an offset=-(original+mirror width), With each loop, offset the images by 1 pixel rightward (offset++).  When the offset is zero, then reset the offset to -(original+mirror).
- **Mouse Control**: You can use the mouse-X position to determine to calculate your desired offset (which in turn determines your position within the infinite panorama).

  ```js
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  var infiniteImage;
  var infiniteImageWidth;
  var img=document.createElement("img");
  img.onload=function(){

    // use a tempCanvas to create a horizontal mirror image
    // This makes the panning appear seamless when
    // transitioning to a new image on the right
    var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCanvas.width=img.width*2;
    tempCanvas.height=img.height;
    tempCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    tempCtx.save();
    tempCtx.translate(tempCanvas.width,0);
    tempCtx.scale(-1,1);
    tempCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    tempCtx.restore();
    infiniteImageWidth=img.width*2;
    infiniteImage=document.createElement("img");
    infiniteImage.onload=function(){
      pan();
    }
    infiniteImage.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
  }
  img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
  img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/mountain.jpg";


  var fps = 60;
  var offsetLeft=0;
  function pan() {

    // increase the left offset
    offsetLeft+=1;
    if(offsetLeft>infiniteImageWidth){ offsetLeft=0; }

    ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,-offsetLeft,0);
    ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,infiniteImage.width-offsetLeft,0);

    setTimeout(function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(pan);
    }, 1000 / fps);
  }
  ```

  ```css
  body{ background-color: ivory; }
  canvas{border:1px solid red;}
  ```

  ```html
  <h4>Infinite panorama using mirror image</h4>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=143></canvas>
  ```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you can run code and simulate them in answers!

Comment: Nice. About your animation loop : setTimeout's accuracy is awful, especially with small delay. Using rAF directly's much smoother (http://jsfiddle.net/dcyy3pdq/1/)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Stack Snippets are new...and cool!  Check them out here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Yes, I grabbed some of my old code. Now its better to use the new timestamp in requestAnimationFrame to handle any desired delays.

Comment: Tjamls @GameAlchemist I'm trying to apply your technique but using mouse position instead of "time" automated loop but I'm getting such weird unexpected results that I'm not sure why or what the cause is

Comment: @Kendall : i'm afraid i don't understand well enough your issues to be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is to do two passes : one down, one up

```
 y1 = y1 >= h? y1 - h : y1; // y1 is the current mouse position on('drag') less the offset  if the position is greater than height of canvas reset with offset
 c.font="20px Georgia";
 c.clearRect(0,0, w, h); // w, h is the width and height of canvas
 c.save();
 var cumulatedHeight=0;
 for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) { // number of images to be drawn to fill area
    var y = y1 + cumulatedHeight; // reposition the images relative to mouse position
    if (y>h) break;
    c.drawImage(im, 0, y, im.width, im.height);
    cumulatedHeight+= im.height;
 }
 cumulatedHeight=0;
 for (var i = numImage-1; i >=0; i--) { // number of images to be drawn to fill area
    cumulatedHeight+= im.height;
    var y = y1 - cumulatedHeight; // reposition the images relative to mouse position
    if (y+im.height<0) break;
    c.drawImage(im, 0, y, im.width, im.height);        
 }
 c.fillText("y: " + y,10,190);
 c.restore();
```

(you might notice i started the work in case you want images with different heights : just add

```
 var im = someImageArray[i];
```

in each for loop.)

Comment: The questioner accidentally posted this comment to you under my answer: @GameAlchemist I'm trying to apply your technique but using mouse position instead of "time" automated loop but I'm getting such weird unexpected results that I'm not sure why or what the cause is –